# How to force the user's mouse scrolling action on to a div, instead of body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I know the title might sound confusing but what I want is really simple. In my design right now, when a user clicks a button the 'body' gets a property of overflow:hidden, and another div appears which has a scroll bar to it's right.

Now, when the div appears and the user tries to scroll using the mouse wheel, nothing happens because that div is not 'targeted' by the browser as it is still probably trying to scroll the body. Of course when the user clicks inside of the div and turns the mouse wheel, or uses the scroll bar of the div, then it scrolls.

I just want that when the div appears, it is automatically targeted without the user having to click inside of it, and simply start using the mouse wheel to scroll the div.

So far I've tried the following:

```
$( ".div-that-appears" ).focus();
```

I've put the above code after the code that shows the div but it doesn't work.

Not sure if it's even possible, but please help if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Capture the `mousewheel` event and scroll the pop up div when showed - its a bit tricky because the `wheelDelta` needs to be parsed correctly:

Explanation:

- `mousewheel` - will fire in almost all browsers.
- `DOMMouseScroll` - will fire in FireFox (Mozilla).

The target is to register the wheel direction and the step (amount of scrolling todo ) The main difference between the two events is the How to get this value:

- `mousewheel` -> `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta`
- `DOMMouseScroll` -> `e.originalEvent.detail`

In `mousewheel` to get the right direction we need to multiply the `wheelDelta` by -1. The values that will be recieved are around `+-30` and will increase if the user will turn his wheel faster and further.

In `DOMMouseScroll` the right direction is already set but we get the steps in steps and not in pixels the values that we recieve are +-1 and will increase up to `~ -+6` if the user will turn his wheel faster and further.
So to normalize this behavior we multiply the `.detail` by 40 or 30 (doesn't mind).

```js
$(function(){
   var $pop = $('.pop').eq(0);
    $('button').click(function(){
        if (!$pop.is(':visible')) {
          $('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){ 
                var scrollTo = 0;
                e.preventDefault(); 
                if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
                        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
                } else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
                        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
                }
                $pop.scrollTop(scrollTo + $pop.scrollTop());
          });
          $pop.fadeIn();
        } else {
          $pop.fadeOut();
          $('body').unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    height:9000px;
}
.pop {
    display:none;
    height:100px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:400px; 
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class='pop' style="height:100px; margin:0 auto; width:400px; border:1px solid black">
    <br/>kgjskjhkasdlk
    <br/>lkasjdlkjlaskdjlk
    <br/>asdkjlkjlklkj
    <br/>kgjskjhkasdlk
    <br/>lkasjdlkjlaskdjlk
    <br/>asdkjlkjlklkj
    <br/>kgjskjhkasdlk
    <br/>lkasjdlkjlaskdjlk
    <br/>asdkjlkjlklkj
    <br/>kgjskjhkasdlk
    <br/>lkasjdlkjlaskdjlk
    <br/>asdkjlkjlklk
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It work perfectly. You made my day.
But can you explain this bit of code:

`if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {

       scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
} else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
                        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
                }`

I still don't know a lot of things in jQuery, and would really like it if u can explain this further. Especially, the significance of multiplying that by 40. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @SameerZahid I'm happy it helped you - its just the start, it can be improved allot more. I added a short explanation on the Two events and how to normalize them.